# Issues Reading HTML File from Folder

Tags: python, html

I have 2 HTML files that I want to read from as though they are websites but I am getting an error on the line starting `date_part` which makes me think I'm not reading the file correctly. The code I use to save to the files:

```
game_links = [
    'https://rugby.statbunker.com/competitions/MatchDetails/Gallagher-Premiership-19/20/Harlequins-VS-Bristol-Bears?comp_id=609&match_id=39862&date=26-Oct-2019',
    'https://rugby.statbunker.com/competitions/MatchDetails/World-Cup-2007/France-VS-Argentina?comp_id=239&match_id=15479&date=07-Sep-2007'
]
for link in game_links:
    response = requests.get(link)
    html_loop = response.content
    soup_loop = BeautifulSoup(html_loop, 'html.parser')
    print(soup_loop)
```

Each output is saved as its own html file. The code I'm running to scrape data off of it:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import time
import uuid

game_links = [open('test1.html', 'r', encoding='utf-8'), open('test2.html', 'r', encoding='utf-8')]

game = {}

for link in game_links:
    soup_loop = link.read()

    game['uuid'] = uuid.uuid1()
    date_part = soup_loop.find('img', {'src': '/images/date.png'}).text
    time_part = soup_loop.find('img', {'src': '/images/kickoff.png'}).text
    if time_part == '':
        game['datetime'] = datetime.strptime(date_part, '%d %b %Y')
    else:
        game['datetime'] = datetime.combine(datetime.strptime(date_part, '%d %b %Y'), datetime.strptime(time_part, '%H:%M').time())
    print(game)
```

Comment: You need to create the soup object first. Mostly you can do: `soup = BeautifulSoup(soup_loop)` then the rest of your code.

Comment: first of all, it is very bad practice to have open files dangling about until you use them.  unless there is a specific reason,  you should have the game_links contain filenames, and open them in the loop, process and close, one by one. regarding the question itself, please add error message you are getting

Answer (score 0):

After reading file it should be parsed again using BeautifulSoup:

```
for link in game_links:
    text = link.read()
    soup_loop = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
    game['uuid'] = uuid.uuid1()
    date_part = soup_loop.find('img', {'src': '/images/date.png'}).text
    time_part = soup_loop.find('img', {'src': '/images/kickoff.png'}).text
    if time_part == '':
        game['datetime'] = datetime.strptime(date_part, '%d %b %Y')
    else:
        game['datetime'] = datetime.combine(datetime.strptime(date_part, '%d %b %Y'), datetime.strptime(time_part, '%H:%M').time())
    print(game)
```